# ADB is working, but fastboot is not on Mac OS X with HTC Desire Z

Tags: fastboot, macos, htc-desire-z

The `adb devices` command is working for me, the `fastboot devices` command is not (Mac OS X Mavericks, SDK downloaded yesterday, the phone is an HTC Desire Z):

```
$ sudo fastboot -i 0x0bb4 -p 0x0c91 devices
$ fastboot -i 0x0bb4 -p 0x0c91 devices
$ fastboot devices
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
HT0C5RT00804    device
$ adb shell
#
```

So fastboot doesn't list devices, whatever I try (`sudo`, or specifying `-i` and `-p` options), while ADB works just fine. I found vendor and product IDs via Mac OS X system information. ADB working seems to indicate that communication between my laptop and the phone does work fine.

How can I get fastboot to work?

**Background info:**

I'm trying to install CyanogenMod on a HTC Desire Z. Part of the procedure I'm following is described here: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/HTC_Desire_Z:_Firmware_Downgrade_(Gingerbread)

I get stuck at the `fastboot oem rebootRUU` step:

```
 $ fastboot oem rebootRUU
 < waiting for device >
```

(hangs, I gave up after 20 minutes), and I think that is due to fastboot not working. Any other ideas on how to get past this appreciated?

Comment: If `adb` is detecting your device then you're in the wrong boot mode for `fastboot`. You need to boot into your bootloader, not the regular Android system or your recovery. You should be able to find instructions for getting into your device's bootloader on Google, I would imagine, but running `adb reboot bootloader` is typically the easiest method.

Comment: Maybe it's a driver issue? Running a linux vm and trying from there might help, or if you want, spend a good amount of time tracking down the proper drivers for your phone and ensure your device is listed with its serial number when you run adb devices in the command line interface.

Answer (score 0):

From your first quoted block, I assume your phone is booted up normally (`adb devices` lists it as "device"). Fastboot cannot find it there. Try `adb reboot fastboot`, then check again when your device has booted up into fastboot mode.

See also:

- [How to Boot Android Devices in various modes (Fastboot/Recovery/Download)](http://www.droidviews.com/how-to-boot-android-devices-in-fastboot-download-bootloader-or-recovery-mode/)
- [fastboot intro](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_fastboot_intro) (CyanogenMod Wiki)
- [FastBoot Mode](http://www.kingoapp.com/help/fastboot-mode.htm) (KingoApp)
- [Know Your Android Tools: What Is Fastboot & How Do You Use It?](http://android.wonderhowto.com/how-to/know-your-android-tools-what-is-fastboot-do-you-use-it-0155640/)
- our [fastboot tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fastboot/info)

Comment: What is the definitive test to know the device is in fastboot mode? tried 'adb reboot fastboot' and power+keydown (and check if its selected in the menu). Anything on the device itself, or via adb shell to definitely see the device being in fastboot mode?

Comment: I've never used fastboot myself, but AFAIK it's definitely showing its own screen on the device (as recovery-mode does as well). So if you see the "standard user UI", I'd say you're definitely not in fastboot mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use `adb reboot bootloader`, and then Mac OS X, assuming the drivers work, will detect it in fastboot mode, as attested to by fastboot devices.

If your Android version is lower than 4.3, use Framaroot to root it, use Flashify to flash a custom recovery, and flash the CyanogenMod rom.zip from the custom recovery. No PC involved.